# Draw Rectangle using OpenLayers 4?

Tags: openlayers

I just want to draw rectangle for style.
if I do this

```
 image: new ol.style.RegularShape({
        fill: fill,
        //stroke: stroke,
        // offsetY: -25,
        points: 4,
        radius1: 30,
        //radius2:20,
        angle: Math.PI / 4
    })
```

it gives me this square 
[image]

else if i do this

```
 image: new ol.style.RegularShape({
        fill: fill,
        //stroke: stroke,
        // offsetY: -25,
        points: 4,
        radius1: 30,
        radius2:10,
        angle: Math.PI / 4
    })
```

it gives me this 
[image]

How can I draw a rectangle?

Comment: Is a rectangle is a regular shape? I think you can not use ol.style.RegularShape to generate a rectangle.

Comment: @jgrocha ol.style includes this classes AtlasManager-
Circle-
Fill-
Icon-
Image-
RegularShape-
Stroke-
Style-
Text

Comment: @jgrocha i think only RegularShape class relevant with Rectangle

Comment: On your style, you have to create a polygon (a new geometry) from the feature's geometry, like in the following example: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/polygon-styles.html
In the example, the second style is based on a new geometry (MultiPoint) based on the feature's geometry.
Try that, and if you can't do it, post here your attempt and we will help you based on your code.

Answer (score 2):

The OpenLayers website has lots of examples that you may find helpful. 
This link goes into details on how to draw shapes.
http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-shapes.html?q=draw

Checkout more on the examples page.